# Getting quotes to show up in PowerShell with 'Invoke-Command' and 'echo'

Tags: powershell, escaping

I am debugging a program, and I am hitting a code path that does this:

```
$a= "-parameter Foo=`"Bar`""
Invoke-Expression "echo $($a)"
```

Output:

```
-parameter
Foo=Bar
```

Note that the quotes around **Bar** are missing. Is there a way to set the value of `$a` (as a double-quoted string) so that the output will be

```
-parameter
Foo="Bar"
```

?

Comment: See also *[Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use single quotes:

```
$a= '-parameter Foo=`"Bar`"'
Invoke-Expression "echo $($a)"
```

Output:

```
-parameter
Foo="Bar"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it if I am forced to use double-quotes?

Comment: Why would you be forced to use double quotes?

Comment: Officially `$a` is a string input to a function.

Comment: Maybe with a more complete example (on another question), we can understand more precisely what problems you are seeing, and what quirks of PowerShell or .NET you might be hitting.